# Bidirectional M2M communication via ethernet (WAN) with raspberry pi

Tags: networking, remote, p2p

I want to run a script remotely on raspberry pi and get feedback. It's easy when I have 1 raspberry pi: I just log in with ssh, do my stuff and see feedback on my remote terminal.

To be precise: the script downloads files from dropbox. And of course raspberries will be spread on huge area so they are not in local network.

But I want to do it with many raspberries (about 100 pieces) at the same time so there must be a better way to do it.

So far I've seen [cgi-style](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/remotely-control-your-raspberry-pi) solutions and e-mailing feedback to gmail.com.

I'd rather have some sort of proprietary server that communicates via [sockets](http://makezine.com/2013/04/22/peertalk-beaglebone-and-raspberry-pi/) to raspberry pi.

Any other solutions?

Comment: You need a command central - The HQ.  It will have a database of what's going on. It can be normal server like nginx or IIS8 that is public facing. All your Pi's will have scripts that ask the master every now and again- "Yo I am @pi number 777 - What's up dude?" The master checks the database if the Boss (You) set any flags for that node and says nothing or run the script now dude or run this shell script, do that, create a reverse tunnel, etc etc. Its not a simple answer and requires allot of work.

Comment: after a while of digging in I've found [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/wtf) and [Pushover](http://www.michaelhleonard.com/send-push-messages-from-beaglebone-black-or-raspberry-pi-to-iphone-or-android/)

Comment: If that answers your question please provide an answer with some example of how its going to work. Very interesting indeed. I would still make my own system but thats just my opinion. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into  [MQTT](http://mqtt.org).  I use [mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org) as my broker(server)/client on the Pi and and knoleary's (knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/) library on several Arduinos. However, there are many other open source MQTT Brokers/Clients available on every platform.

MQTT, Message Queue Telemetry Transport, is a open protocol that implements a publish/subscribe architecture that allows clients to publish (send) information to the broker then allow any number of clients to subscribe (receive) that information. The information does not have to go to any specific user, except to the broker, and multiple clients can be sent the information to use.  Of course there are permissions and encryption available to restrict who can have access.

It is not a ready made script and it will require programming but there are many examples out there.

Comment: this is perfect answer! however for the moment I'll use simple email (i.e. gmail) communication but in the future I'll dig into MQTT, thanks

Comment: If you're digging into MQTT, this 10-part blog post series about in-depth information may help: http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part-1-introducing-mqtt/

Answer (score 1):

I've found something worth considering: https://dweet.io. Maybe also JSON-RPC is worth to look at.